# How to pass Union-typed values to generic function without "isinstance"?

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, mypy

I'm confused about how to store generics/unions in collections. Consider `T` below that can be `bool` or `str`. We can represent this as a bound `TypeVar` or as a `Union`. The difference matters when semantically requiring that the generic is a single type through multiple namings:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Union, List, NoReturn

T = TypeVar("T", bool, str)

T_Union = Union[bool, str]

def generic_function(event: T) -> T:
    # must return same type as passed in
    ...

def union_function(event: T_Union) -> T_Union:
    # can return any type in T_Union, not necessarily what was passed in
    ...
```

Now, if I want to store in a list some valid values that could be passed to these functions, I see that the list type cannot contain an unbound generic, so I store these values in a `Union` where each element is one of the types of `T`:

```py
unbound_list_of_event_types: List[T] = [True, "foo"]  # error: Type variable "__main__.T" is unbound
list_of_event_types: List[T_Union] = [True, "foo"]
```

But, I cannot call the generic function with the `Union`-typed value:

```py
generic_function(list_of_event_types[0])  # error: Value of type variable "T" of "generic_function" cannot be "Union[bool, str]"
union_function(list_of_event_types[0])
```

This strikes me as odd, because if we exhaustively check the types in the `Union`, every function call takes the same form, which looks like needless isinstance-checking:

```py
def assert_never(value: NoReturn) -> NoReturn: ...

# Exhaustively checking the types and calling the function with the *same signature*
if isinstance(list_of_event_types[0], bool):
    generic_function(list_of_event_types[0])
elif isinstance(list_of_event_types[0], str):
    generic_function(list_of_event_types[0])
else:
    assert_never(list_of_event_types[0])

# Seems redundant when we could do this:
generic_function(list_of_event_types[0])  # type: ignore[type-var]
```

https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=0.931&python=3.10&gist=6133504b68fa1e74e844d0fc280ee42f

Is there a better way to store these values in a collection so they can be passed to generic functions?

---

[Simon Hawe's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70844389/5136076) to use `Union` allows this to type check:

```py
T2 = TypeVar("T2", bound=Union[bool, str])

def generic_union_bound_function(event: T2) -> T2:
    # must return same type as passed in
    ...

list_of_event_types: List[Union[bool, str]] = [True, "foo"]

reveal_type(generic_union_bound_function(list_of_event_types[0]))  # bool | str
reveal_type(generic_union_bound_function(True))  # bool
```

But what if we want to use `Type[T]` to deduce the generic? (this example more closely looks like callback registration for various event types). I opened a mypy bug for this case: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `list[Union[t1,t2]]` means that the type is either `t1` or `t2` or `t1` and `t2`. `t1` and `t2` would not be a valid type for something typed with `TypeVar('T', t1, t2)`, as this mean 't1' or 't2' but not both. In your example of `bool` and `str`, there is probably nothing that is both `bool` and `str`, but in general, you could have something like

```py
class X:
    pass

class Y:
   pass

class XY(X,Y):
   pass

T_U = Union[X,Y]

x : T_U = X()
y : T_U = Y()
xy : T_U = XY()
```

Now, what you could use for your example would be a TypeVar that is bound to the Union of bool and str. If you type a function with that, it would still resolve to input type is equal to the output type. It would additionally allow the potential type that is a type of both types from the union. This, however, is anyways not really possible for bool and str. So if you try that code

```py
T = TypeVar("T", bound= Union[bool, str])
def some_function(e:TR) -> TR:
    ...
    
a = some_function"a")
b = some_function(1)

d = a.split() # works
c = b.split() # works error: "int" has no attribute "split"
```

it will exactly check for what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for shedding a light here! From PEP 484 "A type factored by Union[T1, T2, ...] is a supertype of all types T1, T2, etc.", which is what you describe. In this example, rather than have two bounds `bool` and `str`, a single `Union` bound allows the list element to satisfy the bound.

Comment: I thought figuring out the `Union` trick would solve my callback registration problem, but it didn't. I edited the question to include the use case for deducing `T` through `Type[T]`.

Comment: I marked this as accepted because my follow-up is a separate question. And after further inspection of my code, I think your answer solves my problem, and my follow-up isn't the reality I'm dealing with. Thanks again!